# Blank line before block statements

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

Is it possible in eclipse to configue a formatter or a clean-up to insert a blank linke before or after a block statement?

Instead of this:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (obj == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (ids.length > 0) {
        System.out.println(ids[0]);
    } else {
        return;
    }
    try {
    }
    catch( Exception e) {
    }
    finally {
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    }
    switch( p) {
      case 0:
        fField.set( 0);
        break;
      case 1: {
        break;
      }
      default:
        fField.reset();
    }    

  }
}
```

I'd like to have this:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (obj == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    if (ids.length > 0) {
        System.out.println(ids[0]);
    } else {
        return;
    }

    try {
    }
    catch( Exception e) {
    }
    finally {
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    }

    switch( p) {
      case 0:
        fField.set( 0);
        break;
      case 1: {
        break;
      }
      default:
        fField.reset();
    }    

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem possible looking at the Blank Lines settings (see screenshot below), as no such configuration is available here; and the Eclipse Java Code formatter settings are configured in this central location.

[image: Java code formatter profile]

Comment: But note the "Number of empty lines to preserve" setting! If the blank lines are added manually, at least they will not get removed.